# Wordpress: Category Post Count

Tags: php, wordpress, function, increment, wp-list-categories

I am trying to figure out a way to get the number of posts in a specific category, then display the posts number on the post itself. To better explain, I'm creating a portfolio section on my site and rather than displaying the posts id as the increment (because my id's are not in order), I'd rather somehow count the posts in my portfolio category and display the increment. Example picture below.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the posts count number in the specific category? So if you have 5 posts in Friends category, the first one will be story no. 1?

Comment: @JayDev95 Correct, I'm looking to get the post count in a specific category, then display the increment on the post. Like in the example, there are 22 posts in the category "Portfolio". I always order posts by "Descending" so that's why Story No. 22 is first. I'm familiar with how to get the total posts count in a category, I'm just not sure how to show the increment on the post like in the image I provided above (increment is shown at the top of the image). Hope this further clarifies my question!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `$wp_query` and get the post index in the loop. See the below example. `current_post` will get the index of that post in the loop. The index starts at 0 so we add one to it so it will start counting at 1.

In `functions.php`:

```
function namespace_post_index() {
  global $wp_query;
  
  $postIndex = $wp_query->current_post + 1;

  echo $postIndex;

}
```

In the loop, use the function we created above:

```
namespace_post_index();
```